# Extjs 5.0, add dynamically an item to an accordian

Tags: javascript, extjs

i want to add dynamically items to my accordion layout when items are added the collapse buttons are not working.

if i add items directly - not dynamically- it works fine. if you have please a simple example how to do it, i will appreciate your help.
below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="framework/packages/ext-theme-gray/build/resources/ext-theme-gray-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="framework/build/ext-all.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="framework/build/packages/ext-theme-gray/build/ext-theme-gray.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script >
        Ext.onReady(function(){

        var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
            layout: 'border',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [
                {
                region: 'west',
                id: 'west-panel', // see Ext.getCmp() below
                layout: {
                    type: 'accordion',
                    titleCollapse: false,
                    animate: true,
                    activeOnTop: true
                },
                title: 'West',
                split: true,
                width: 300,
                minWidth: 175,
                maxWidth: 400,
                collapsible: false,
               animCollapse: false,
                margins: '0 0 0 5',
                items: [{id: 'generalParam' ,title: 'General Param'                 ,iconCls: 'nav' ,
                dockedItems: [{xtype: 'toolbar',dock: 'left',margins: '5 5 5 5',
                                items: [
                                        {xtype: 'button',text: 'Currency'   ,iconCls:'chr'}, 
                                        {xtype: 'button',text: 'Area'       ,iconCls:''},
                                        {xtype: 'button',text: 'Bank'       ,iconCls:''},
                                        {xtype: 'button',text: 'Network'    ,iconCls:''},
                                        {xtype: 'button',text: 'MCC'        ,iconCls:''},
                                        {xtype: 'button',text: 'Static Data',iconCls:''},
                                        {xtype: 'button',text: 'Interfaces' ,iconCls:''},
                                        {xtype: 'button',text: 'Sequences'  ,iconCls:''},
                                        {xtype: 'button',text: 'MCC'        ,iconCls:''}
                                ]}]

                                }
                ]
            },
            Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
                region: 'center', // a center region is ALWAYS required for border layout
                deferredRender: false,
                items: [{
                    bodyStyle: 'background-image:url(images/square.gif)',
                    html: 'Internal notes go here',
                    title: 'Welcome',
                    closable: true,
                    autoScroll: true
                }]
            }),         {
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                autoShow:true,
                region: 'east',
                title: 'Information',
                animCollapse: true,
                collapsible: true,
                split: true,
                width: 275, // give east and west regions a width
                minSize: 175,
                maxSize: 400,
                margins: '0 5 0 0',
                activeTab: 1,
                tabPosition: 'bottom',
                items: [{
                    html: '<p>A TabPanel component can be a region.</p>',
                    title: 'A Tab',
                    autoScroll: true
                }, Ext.create('Ext.grid.PropertyGrid', {
                        title: 'Property Grid',
                        closable: false,
                        source: {
                            "(name)": "Properties Form",
                            "grouping": false,
                            "autoFitColumns": true,
                            "productionQuality": false,
                            "created": Ext.Date.parse('10/15/2006', 'm/d/Y'),
                            "tested": false,
                            "version": 0.01,
                            "borderWidth": 1
                        }
                    })]
            },
            {
                xtype:'panel',
                region: 'south',
                split: true,
                height: 100,
                minSize: 100,
                maxSize: 200,
                collapsible: true,
                collapsed: true,
                title: 'South',
                margins: '10 10 10 10'
            }
            ]
            }); 


            var item1 = {id: 'cardSetting'  ,title: 'Card Settings'                 ,iconCls: 'settings'}; 
            var item2 ={title: 'new item'               ,iconCls: 'crv' };

            Ext.getCmp('west-panel').add(item1);
            Ext.getCmp('west-panel').add(item2);
            Ext.getCmp('west-panel').doLayout();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified your code a little so that its a bit more specific to the issue, in simplifying it I'm not able to replicate the issue anymore. I'm presuming your using ExtJs 3 due to the `Ext.onReady` code.

When I first copied your code, there were errors showing regarding the use of Ext.create in the middle for the tab panel, So I removed the panel, The default type is a panel so there is no need for this.

Here is the code I am currently testing against:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: 'border',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [
            {
                region: 'west',
                id: 'west-panel', // see Ext.getCmp() below
                layout: {
                    type: 'accordion',
                    titleCollapse: false,
                    animate: true,
                    activeOnTop: true
                },
                title: 'West',
                split: true,
                width: 300,
                minWidth: 175,
                maxWidth: 400,
                collapsible: false,
                animCollapse: false,
                margins: '0 0 0 5',
                items: [{
                    id: 'generalParam',
                    title: 'General Param',
                    iconCls: 'nav',
                    html: '<p>Panel content!</p>'
                }, {
                    id: 'cardSetting',
                    title: "Card Settings",
                    iconCls: "settings",
                    html: '<p>Panel content!</p>'
                }]
            },
            {
                region: 'center', // a center region is ALWAYS required for border layout
                deferredRender: false,
                items: [{
                    bodyStyle: 'background-image:url(images/square.gif)',
                    html: 'Internal notes go here',
                    title: 'Welcome',
                    closable: true,
                    autoScroll: true
                }]
            }
        ]
    });


    var item1 = {id: 'cardSetting2', title: 'Card Settings2', iconCls: 'settings', html: '<p>Panel content!</p>'};
    var item2 = {title: 'new item 3', iconCls: 'crv', html: '<p>Panel content!</p>'};

    Ext.getCmp('west-panel').add(item1);
    Ext.getCmp('west-panel').add(item2);
    Ext.getCmp('west-panel').doLayout();
});
```

Could you try this code and see if you still get the issue, if so please provide details and I will update this answer with a response. Good luck with the project.

**EDIT**: Please see working [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gap)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i have tried your code but the issue is still the same, the collapse button for two items you add (new item 3) and (card setting 2) is not working  so content is not shown. i want inform that i am using EXTJS version 5.

Comment: I have added a link to a sencha fiddle above in my answer, in that fiddle I have 4 menu items in the accordion and I have content in each? Could you explain what issue you are seeing that I am not?

Comment: you have added two items dynamically, item1 and item2. the issue is that i can't open any of them to see the content. nothing happen if i click on those items.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the issue by adding an listener beforerender,
listeners: {beforerender:addAccordion}
and define a function addAccordion as below:

var addAccordion    =   function(){
        var accordion_panel=Ext.getCmp('west-panel');
        var item1 = {id: 'cardSetting'  ,title: 'Card Settings'                 ,iconCls: 'settings'}; 
        var item2 ={title: 'new item'               ,iconCls: 'crv' };
        accordion_panel.add(item1);
        accordion_panel.add(item2);
 };
Thanks